# Java ClassCastException confusion

Tags: java, casting

I have the following code:

```
PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Double>> pq = 
      new PriorityQueue<>((v1, v2) -> (int)Math.floor(v1.getValue() - v2.getValue()));
pq.add(new Pair(1, 0));
Pair<Integer, Double> node = pq.poll();
double time = node.getValue();
```

The last line raises a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class
java.lang.Double (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Double are in module 
java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

The issue goes away if I replace the second statement with

```
pq.add(new Pair(1, 0.0));
```

I'd like to understand what is happening under the hood resulting in this exception.

Comment: What is `Pair`?  Is that a standard class?

Answer (score 2):

An `int` can be cast to a `double`, but an `Integer` can't be cast to a `Double`.

When you instantiate your `Pair<Integer, Double>`, both `int` values that you're passing are getting autoboxed to `Integer`.  But what you needed was an `Integer` and a `Double`.

Comment: I think the OP is expecting that the declaration `PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Double>>` will force the int to a Double when `new Pair` is executed.  But I'm not 100% sure that's what they're asking about either.